# Permission level for customers

Tags: office-365

I want to create permissions for an user to view the files in a library and be able to download them. I set up the "Read" permission but there is not option to download the file to a local machine. Is there a workaround where people can view the file and download a local copy but they cannot edit the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Read' permission should give permission to Download Copy.If it's not working then follow these steps:

- Go to Library Settings > Advanced Settings
- Make sure that ***Allow items from this document library to be downloaded to offline clients?***  is Set to ***Yes***. (Offline Client Availability)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible. If these are Office documents then you could try the 'View Only' permission.  This allows your users to open the Office document within the browser (not downloadable).

Comment: If they can download files.  They can edit files.  If you dont want users to edit files then you would need to give them "View" permission and let them open it in browser via Office Web App-This is assuming they are trying to view MS Office supported files.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, Read permission sohuld give to option to download files. 
To check this, select the document with read permission, on ribbon check button " Download a copy" is this enabled or disabled ?