# Can a document be view-only?

Tags: roles, document

We have a very specific requirement in our CMS to make documents view only. The business users do not mean to make them non-editable - they want to prevent the users from downloading the document to their hard disks too. Something like an online view.
Current implementation we have is a role-based check to prevent users from checking in an updated version of the document. But the users still can get a copy of the document downloaded to their disk.

Is it possible to implement the above requirement in Sharepoint?

Comment: What version of SharePoint? You might be able to use [IRM](http://www.titus.com/blog/2012/11/spc12-diary-day-5-%E2%80%93-information-rights-management-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 1):

A determined user will find a way to save the text of such documents if they really feel the need to do so - anything from copy/paste to taking screenshots (even possibly performing OCR on those screenshots). The only way to prevent this with any degree of confidence is to have restrictions in place on each client machine accessing the documents.

Comment: Agreed. This is exactly what I said when I heard the requirement. Anyway, requirements are strange and we have to do what we can do with caveats

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, It is possible in Sharepoint.

Follow my answer here : [Set Offline Client Availability of sharepoint document library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132878/permission-level-for-customers/132938#132938)

You have to set ***Offline Client Availability*** to ***No***

Comment: Thanks will read further, and accept if this serves as a solution.